# Bootstrap 4 horizontal scroller div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I got this working for Bootstrap 3 but the same code won't work in Bootstrap 4.

Basically, I'm trying to create a horizontal scroll for DIV and here's a working JSFIDDLE for Bootstrap 3 (which I don't want): [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/zaazhp2d/)

The same code for Bootstrap 4 isn't working though! Here's the JSFiddle for Bootstrap 4: [**https://jsfiddle.net/6kvw2q5h/**](https://jsfiddle.net/6kvw2q5h/)

HTML

```
<div class="live__scroll">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.live__scroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.live__scroll .live__scroll--box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm at wits end.

Answer (score 16):

HTML

```
<div class="container testimonial-group">
    <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">7</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">8</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* The heart of the matter */
.testimonial-group > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.testimonial-group > .row > .col-sm-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

/* Decorations */
.col-sm-4 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; }
.col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
.col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

NOTE : [codepen](https://codepen.io/inewton/pen/LeEbVL)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the flexbox functionality of the `.row` so add:

```
.live__scroll .row{
  display:block;
}
```

So it should look like the following:

```css
.live__scroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.live__scroll .row{
  display:block;
}
.live__scroll .live__scroll--box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="live__scroll">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
    <div class="col-8 live__scroll--box">1</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### horizontal scoll bar using bootstrap 4

### In table

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>bharti</td>
          <td>parmar</td>
          <td>422</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

### In navigation bar

```
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>

</div>
```

### css code

```
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```