# Bootstrap 4 prevent clipping on overflowing row with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, scroll, bootstrap-4, overflow, clipping

I created a `row` with horizontal scrolling for all contained `col`.

I used an answer to this question: [Bootstrap 4 horizontal scroller div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733537/bootstrap-4-horizontal-scroller-div)

However, I found that the elements inside the `container` are clipped. Now on some OS-Browser combinations (e.g. MacOS+Chrome) the scrollbar is hidden unless it is hovered by the mouse and in a test one of our users was not able to find the next (clipped) `col` element.

I'd like to know how to "unclip" the elements beyond the container width, so that user can immediately see that there is more content that requires scrolling.

**Edit:**

The related code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793060/3098783), and also posted on [codepen](https://codepen.io/inewton/pen/LeEbVL).

**Edit 2:**

Note, that I want to prevent the container from being moved on scroll.

Comment: Can you post the code you've attempted?

Comment: The code is in the linked question and I did not copy it because I don't want to pretend it is my code.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you mean clipped because of the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: The elements beyond the width of the `container` are hidden (is clipped the right term for that?) and I'd like to keep them visible so people can see, that there are more elements that can be reached when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: I updated my question, as the link was too unspecific.

Comment: Are you looking into making the horizontal scrollbar visible in all browsers or show in some manner that there is more content to the right-hand side that can be scrolled to?

Comment: The second one but without scrolling the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbars staying hidden is an OSX feature that users have to opt-out from if they want scrollbars to stay visible. There is not much that you can do to force them to stay visible. But you could style them explicitly so chrome and safari will show then at least.

You could test for Mac Os and chrome / safari combo, as this is a platform specific problem. Then you can override the styling for the scrollbar. This forces it to be shown.

```
.testimonial-group > .row {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.testimonial-group > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #F5F5F5;
}


.testimonial-group > .row::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 0px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.testimonial-group > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   background-color: #555;
}
```

Comment: The scrollbar is on my OSX also hidden on Firefox and Safari when opening the codepen from the question. Adding the css you posted made the scrollbar actually disappear =0 (Reproduce: OSX 10.14.3, Chrome 72.0.3626.119, FF 65.0.1, Safari 12.0.3)

Comment: Ah yes because I also set overflow-x to scroll. I edited my post to clarify.

Comment: This is working. However I would like to wait until the end of the bounty period to see if there is still a solution that prevents the elements from being clipped when scrolling is active. If there won't be any viable answer I will accept this one as a compromise solution.

Comment: Yes, please leave it open, if there is another way to force scrollbars on OSX I would like to know it as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you want it as table-responsive in which all the divs by default take equal width of the available width of the parent, then you shouldn't use `col-sm-4`.
The divs with this class will have **33.33% width** of the parent and your others divs will surely not visible with this.

So for responsive divs you can edit this code in this way. [Added link for Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drmvxe)

```
<div class="container testimonial-group">
 <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap">
 <div class="col">1</div><!--
  --><div class="col">2</div><!--
  --><div class="col">3</div><!--
  --><div class="col">4</div><!--
  --><div class="col">5</div><!--
  --><div class="col">6</div><!--
  --><div class="col">7</div><!--
  --><div class="col">8</div><!--
  --><div class="col">9</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* The heart of the matter */
.testimonial-group > .row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.testimonial-group > .row > .col-sm-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
 }

 /* Decorations */
.col { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; 
}
.col:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
.col:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately does this cause the container to be moved by horizontal scrolling, too. The reference to `table-responsive` was just for giving an example of how it should behave.

Comment: I just checked and I think `table-responsive` is a bad reference here. I just really want to prevent the clipping when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the default scroll bar colors  and behaviour

```
.row {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col-sm-4 {
 display: inline;
 align-items: left;
 justify-content: left;
}
/*scroll bar style all brwosers expet IE && Firefox*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #787c7d;
}
```

Otherwise  you could do it with JS instead of css

Comment: But this also just manipulates the scrollbar. This could be an alternative solution but I'd still like to see if the clipping could be circumvented.

Comment: I'm thinking this is more a ux-problem than a code-problem. You have some sideway-scrolling content with no indication that scrolling is possible. A scrollbar is a good indication, but OSX has removed them, and even though you can force them back into webkit, that still leaves FF. It seems you want the possibility of scroll to become apparent when the user starts to interact with the element. So that still leaves the possibility of it not being discovered. Why not just expose a bit of the 4th box.

Comment: That exposing of the 4 th box was already on my mind but how achieve this with Bootstrap's 12 sized grid with elements below 5?